# DID with Panel data (FE) - insignificant results

Tags: panel-data, fixed-effects-model, generalized-did

I run a DID with Panel data (FE) in Stata. I have two groups, Treatment Group (N=75); Control group (N=54). And have a time series of 6, 3 pre treatment and 3 post treatment. I am getting insignificant results, and do not know how to explain it?  I run a placebo test, still insignificant results. Can someone help me elaborate the reasons. Is the sample size not large? What could have been wrong?

The variable of interest is the change of a sustainability score of ocmpanies.Treated is a dummy that takes 1 for the period and being in the treatment country. I use Size (total assets of companies) as control variable.

this is my regression:

reghdfe esg c.Treated#c.post  Size , absorb(country year industry) cluster(country industry)

Moreover, these are my results:

[image: Regression output]

I would really appreciate an answer, thank you!

Comment: The most common reason to get insignificant results is that any effect that might be present is too small for your experiment to detect.  That's essentially a restatement of the definition of statistical significance.  We would be happy to help you go further with your *post mortem,* but you first need to give us the details of your data and results.